# Access violation writing location

Tags: c++-cli

При закрытии формы возникает ошибка Access violation writing location.

Подключение модулей и структуры:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
struct team
{
    char name[50];
    int score;
};
team *teams;


using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace std;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
```

Функция MarshalString:

```
    void MarshalString ( String ^ s, string& os ) {
        using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;
        const char* chars = (const char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(s)).ToPointer();
        os = chars;
        Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr((void*)chars));
    }
```

Код:

```
void readFromDGV()
{
    try
    {       
        for(int i=0;i<dataGridView1->RowCount-1;i++)
        {
            String^ tname=Convert::ToString(dataGridView1->Rows[i]->Cells[0]->Value->ToString());
            string sname;
            MarshalString(tname,sname);
            strncpy_s(teams[i].name,sname.c_str(),sizeof(teams[i].name));
            teams[i].score=Convert::ToInt32(dataGridView1->Rows[i]->Cells[1]->Value);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ^ex){};

}

void enterIntoDGV()
{
    try
    {
        for(int i=1;i<dataGridView1->RowCount;i++)
        {
            string str0(teams[i].name);
            String ^st0=gcnew String(str0.c_str());
            dataGridView1->Rows[i-1]->Cells[0]->Value=st0;
            dataGridView1->Rows[i-1]->Cells[1]->Value=teams[i].score.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ^ex){};
}

private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             int n=dataGridView1->RowCount-1;
             teams=new team[n];
             readFromDGV();
             team temp;
             for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1->RowCount; i++)
             {
                 for (int j = i + 1; j < dataGridView1->RowCount; j++)
                 {

                    if (teams[i].score>teams[j].score)
                    {
                        temp = teams[j];
                        teams[j] = teams[i];
                        teams[i] = temp;
                    }
                 }
             }
             enterIntoDGV();

         }

private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         readFromDGV();
         team temp;
         for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1->RowCount; i++)
         {
             for (int j = i + 1; j < dataGridView1->RowCount; j++)
             {

                if (teams[i].score>teams[j].score)
                {
                    temp = teams[j];
                    for (int k = j; k>i; k--) teams[k] = teams[k - 1];
                    teams[i] = temp;
                }
             }
         }
         enterIntoDGV();
        }
```

Ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]